# Maxwell equations: Lagrangian or Eulerian description

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, continuum-mechanics

I am just wondering the 4 Maxwell equations (i.e Fadaray Law, Maxwell-Ampere) are Lagrangian or Eulerian description? Does it really matter?

Comment: I've only heard that distinction made with respect to fluid mechanics. What do you mean by an "Eulerian" description of E&M?

Comment: Magnetohydrodynamics combine Maxwell's equations with Navier-Stokes fluid equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics which is typically done in the Eulerian approach, I think, e.g. using bulk plasma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction between the two descriptions you consider assumes that there is a field of velocities describing the motion of the particles of the continuous body.

Adopting one or the other description respectively means (a) to use the initial position of the particles to label the integral curves of the field  (Lagrangian description) or (b) to refer  to the istantaneous  positions of particles in a given rest space (Eulerian description).

The electromagnetic field does not provide this field of velocities so that the choice does not make much sense. Or maybe, to some extent we can say that  only the Eulerian description can be adopted.

The EM field is not a continuous body or a fluid, even if it shares some features with these physical systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now for the electric field example, does it propagate accordingly to his vector direction or to the wave (perpendicular to the Magnetic and Electric Field)?

Comment: Yes, the Poyning vector field satisfies a conservation equation with respect to the density of electromagnetic  energy that shares some similarities with the continuity equation of the mass. But it is not enough to describe the EM system as a continuum within  the classical view.

Comment: But they are always presented in two ways, called differential, with nablas and curls and dels. And called integral, with confusing surface integrals and stuff. Is that different?